# Calling a generic method multiple times based on fixed list of type

Tags: c#

I have a generic method `Method<T>()` and I have a list of types like below :

```
public static readonly Type[] AllPossibleTypes = new Type[]{
        typeof(A),
        typeof(B),
        typeof(C),
        typeof(D)
};
```

There are multiple place in my code that I would have to `switch case` and do pattern matching, then finally call each one manually e.g. `Method<A>` `Method<B>` `Method<C>` ... then when I decided to add more type to the list of possible type I would have to remember to fix many places in the code. Is there any approach to iterate through possible types and have it usable with generic? The list of type will not change at runtime.

`A B C D` implements the same interface and no other type implements that interface, if that would help me achieve this goal.

```
public interface IToIntCompatible
{
    int ToInt();
}

public struct A : IToIntCompatible
{
    public string data;
    public int ToInt() => data.ToArray().GetHashCode();
}

public struct B : IToIntCompatible
{
    public float data;
    public int ToInt() => (int)Math.Round(data);
}

public struct C : IToIntCompatible
{
    public bool data;
    public int ToInt() => -1;
}


public class Example
{
    /// <summary>
    /// I wish I can add type D in the future without having to touch PlaceA and PlaceB
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly Type[] allTypes = new Type[] { typeof(A), typeof(B), typeof(C) };

    /// <summary>
    /// Cannot modify this function.
    /// </summary>
    private void Save<T>(T data) where T : struct { }

    public void PlaceA(IToIntCompatible input)
    {
        switch (input)
        {
            case A a: Save<A>(a); break;
            case B b: Save<B>(b); break;
            case C c: Save<C>(c); break;
        }
    }

    public void PlaceB(IToIntCompatible input)
    {
        switch (input)
        {
            case A a: Save<A>(a); break;
            case B b: Save<B>(b); break;
            case C c: Save<C>(c); break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like generics isn't a good fit here. What's wrong with just each type implementing  the interface? Sure, you could make a `Dictionary` between `Type` and method name and call it with reflection but aren't you just re-inventing polymorphism?

Comment: The API which I have no way to fix only accept generic, let's say `Exist<T>` and it let you search for any struct type in the database. In my program I have several type of struct I want to check (all of them implementing the same interface), I wish I would be able to iterate through the list of type and call `Exist<T>` on them one by one.

Comment: Can you post the code that uses the variable you defined?  Reflection and dynamic methods are both possibilities.

Comment: Could you show us one of your switch case?

Comment: I have added the code sample.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use reflection to call generic methods with dynamic choosen type argument.

```
typeof(Example).GetMethod("Save").MakeGeneric(input.GetType()).Invoke(this, new object[]{input});
```

Comment: Not strictly true.  You don't "*have*" to use reflection.  If this was on my hot path there's no way I would ever even consider reflection.

Comment: @Zer0 - I don't understand the last sentence in your comment?

Comment: @Enigmativity Hm, let me rephrase.  The verbose meaning of hot path is "code execution paths in which most of the execution time is spent".  Put simply, code run most (or very) often.  The second part is self explanatory.  Reflection is [relatively] *extremely* slow.  That's well known.

Comment: @Enigmativity A great example of how slow reflection is can be demonstrated by an extremely simple class: `class ImGeneric<T> where T : new() { public T ReallySlow() { return new T(); } }`.  That actually uses reflection under the covers calling `Activator.CreateInstance`.  It is many orders of magnitude slower than something like `new NonGenericType();`

Comment: @Zer0 - I just tried creating a `class Foo { }` object 10,000,000 times in a loop to fill an array. Using `new Foo()` it takes about 963 ms and using `(Foo)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Foo))` it takes about 1,374 ms. For a single order of magnitude it should take 9,630 ms. It's no where near "many orders of magnitude".

Comment: @Enigmativity - Those results seem absolutely bizarre to me.  Most recent .NET framework version and Visual Studio I presume?  I'll attempt to reproduce your benchmark.  Disclaimer:  I work in the trading industry and measure in nanoseconds and not milliseconds.  Milliseconds = bankrupt for us.  My performance standards are [unreasonably] high for most.

Comment: @Zer0 - Here's my code: https://pastebin.com/3Ad0wVeJ . The latest run is `963.65864` versus `1586.02459`.

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm getting 87 ms versus 961 ms.  I'll concede it's a single order of magnitude.  But will stand by my statement that reflection is well known to be slow.  They must have improved performance since I last profiled or benchmarked however.  Still a very large difference.  I can post my code somewhere if you'd like.  I am accounting for JIT time and GC time.

Comment: @Zer0 - It took a while, but I figured out the difference between your code and mine. It's the assignment. If you do just `action();` then you get times like 45 ms, but if you do `foos[i] = action();` then the time is like 875 ms for the basic `new Foo()`. (I have to change `Action action` to `Func<Foo> action`.)

Comment: @Enigmativity -  I didn't want to measure that, intentionally.  It introduces the CPU cache plus something I don't want to measure.  That said, my version does indeed construct 20 million objects (and cleans the heap).  My final run with all my cores at ~0%, release build, no debugger attached is `38 ms` versus `918 ms` seen [here](https://imgur.com/a/lP67rIR).  I'd really like to bench only the construction itself.  Your method solves the GC cost by using the LOH and a contiguous block, and I solve it by cleaning the heap.  Weird results, I'd have to deep dive this.

Comment: @Zer0 - It's not a lot of point just benchmarking the creation only. If arguing real-world impacts the benchmark should be for a real-world scenario. No-one creates 20,000,000 objects without keeping a reference somewhere.

Comment: @Enigmativity Of course.  But you are measuring far more than just object creation.  When doing an assignment to a [very large] array you're involving the CPU cache pipeline heavily.  I'd be willing to bet if you created 10 million member variables instead you would see results like mine.  Whether I store them or they get collected is irrelevant here.  I want to measure *solely* how long it takes to construct.  Everything else is noise.  Our use case is a generic-based lock-free object pool which uses dynamic methods because of how very slow `new T()` is.  My benchmark undeniably shows that.

Comment: @Enigmativity Eliminating your huge array and replacing it with a class member `private static Foo foo;` and constantly assigning to that gives me no real change in results.  It's your array (and various implications) that's slowing down normal construction to make `new T()` only *appear* to be twice as slow.  Instead of a magnitude slower.  In short I don't think your benchmark is a fair one.  You are measuring more than you think.  And it's not the cost of the assignment.  I do regularly heavily optimize CPU cache pipeline usage but that's *wayyyy* off-topic.  A fun exercise though.

Answer (score 1):

One option to *consider* is dynamic typing:

```
public void PlaceA(IToIntCompatible input)
{
    Save((dynamic) input);
}
```

That will perform generic type inference for you, as if you'd specified the actual execution-time type of `input`.

It's equivalent to writing the reflection-based code, but much simpler code. I'm not a big fan of using dynamic typing, but if you genuinely can't change anything else, it *may* be the simplest solution here.

Comment: This is interesting, I did not know we can omit generic type with `dynamic`. If `Save` does not take any argument (take only type T) and I could not use `dynamic` then the best way is to use reflection?

Comment: @5argon That depends on "best".  I'd say it's the most simple and elegant solution.  Keep in mind that reflection is *very* slow.  A faster implementation would be using dynamic methods.  But if this isn't the hot path or not performance critical then no need to optimize it.

Comment: @Zer0: Dynamic typing infrastructure manages to cache a lot of the binding decisions, and can be pretty quick. But your point of not trying to optimize something that's unimportant is a very important one.

Comment: @5argon: You could potentially add an intermediate method that *does* take a `T`, use that for type inference, and make that just call `Save<T>()`.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I'm mixed on your comment.  I tend to side with [Joe Duffy](http://joeduffyblog.com/2010/09/06/the-premature-optimization-is-evil-myth/) on this point.  But I am biased.  Most coders are not held to the extreme performance requirements of the trading industry.  So yes, I did note for most cases the performance hit, while still significant, is likely moot in most cases.

Comment: @Zer0: I think there tends to be a big difference between library code and application code. For application code, you typically have a much better idea of who's going to call it and what the performance requirements are. Library code can often be used in ways the author had never imagined, where performance is more important.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I definitely agree with that.  Knowing when performance is important, and to what degree, is just as equal as knowing what something costs.  Here a dynamic method implementation emitting IL is complete overkill in most cases.  In some cases it's not.  I only wanted to note it so one can make a well informed decision.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does the job:

```
public class Example
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Cannot modify this function.
    /// </summary>
    private void Save<T>(T data) where T : struct { }

    public void PlaceA(IToIntCompatible input)
    {
        typeof(Example)
            .GetMethod("Save")
            .MakeGenericMethod(input.GetType())
            .Invoke(this, new object[] { input });
    }

    public void PlaceB(IToIntCompatible input)
    {
        typeof(Example)
            .GetMethod("Save")
            .MakeGenericMethod(input.GetType())
            .Invoke(this, new object[] { input });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> "A B C D implements the same interface and no other type implements
>   that interface, if that would help me achieve this goal."

¿Has this interface implements your Method? If not you'll need to add this method to this interface or use a new one.

Edited with last update:

```
public interface IToIntCompatible
{
    int ToInt();
}

public interface ISaveCompatible
{
    void Save();
}

public struct A : IToIntCompatible, ISaveCompatible
{
    public string data;

    public void Save()
    {
        // save function for A type
    }

    public int ToInt() => data.ToArray().GetHashCode();
}

public struct B : IToIntCompatible, ISaveCompatible
{
    public float data;

    public void Save()
    {
        // save function for B type
    }

    public int ToInt() => (int)Math.Round(data);
}

public struct C : IToIntCompatible
{
    public bool data;
    public int ToInt() => -1;
}


public class Example
{
    public void Place(ISaveCompatible input)
    {
        input.Save();
    }
}
```

You don't need generics for this solution.